# ng-class on $scope.$watch does not work on 2nd click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys my code is working fine when clicking the ng-click to toggle the checkbox, and if the checkbox is **unchecked**, it can be checked when inputting numbers in the **input tag** through $scope.$watch() . But when I click the 'toggleCheckBox()' to **uncheck** the CheckBox of 'Shopping' label after I input numbers, the ng-class is not working. the $scope.$watch() is displaying the "Hello World!" but not initializing $scope.checkShopping = true; What could be the problem?
Here's the code. Thank you so much!

```js
$scope.toggleCheckbox = function (mainModel, subModel) {

        var index = $scope[mainModel].indexOf(subModel);
        if (index >= 0) {
            $scope[mainModel].splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            $scope[mainModel].push(subModel);
        }
    };


$scope.$watch('Shopping',function(){
  if($scope.Shopping > 0){
    $scope.checkShopping = true; //this code is not working on 2nd input. The ng-class is not setting to 'TRUE'
  console.log("Hello world!");
  }
});
```

```css
 .checkListHolder {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .checkListHolder > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 0;
 }

 .checkedListItem .checkboxList {
  background-image: url(../images/form-icons/checkbox-on.png);
 }

 .checkboxList {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../images/form-icons/checkbox-off.png);
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .checkboxLabel {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif!important;
 }
```

```html
<li ng-class="{checkedListItem : checkShopping == true}">
  <div class="checkboxList" ng-click="toggleCheckbox('PleasureVacationList','Shopping')">  </div>
  <div class="checkboxLabel">Shopping</div>
</li>
<li>
  <input type="number" ng-model="Shopping">
</li>
```

What can be the problem? Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the problems with assigning a variable directly on the scope. Because you change the pointer, and not just the value of the variable, angular's digest cycle does not pick up the change. There are multiple fixes for that:

```
/* 1: apply the function in the digest cycle */
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.checkShopping = true;
});

/* 2: apply to the whole digest cycle */
$scope.checkShopping = true;
$scope.$apply();

/* 3: use an object with initialization */
$scope.shopping = {
    checkShopping: false
}

// then the following will be picked up by angular's digest cycle:
$scope.shopping.checkShopping = true;
```

[Here's](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) a good explanation on the **why** this is happening

Comment: How come Angular doesn't notice this, although it is in its $scope and all?

Comment: It's still not working devqon... After inputing numbers then toggle to uncheck the checkbox. I input number to the input tag but the  $scope.checkShopping = true; is not working

Comment: Please include a jsfiddle to reproduce

Comment: I'm having an error 'Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress'
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest

Comment: hi @devqon your code is working. I guess some JQuerry of mine is causing the problem. Thank you for your help!